# How to block a wildcard subdomain in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

So I am able to block specific subdomains like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer knownsub\.sorryspammer\.com sorryspammer

<Location />
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=sorryspammer
</Location>
```

which does successfully block visits to any site on my server that come from the referrer, knownsub.sorryspammer.com

So now, I am getting visits from referrers like 1.sorryspammer.com, 2.sorryspammer.com, 8.sorryspammer.com, 22.sorryspammer.com, etc., and I need to set an environment variable to block any subdomain coming from the referrer domain sorryspammer.com.

I know I need to set the same basic rule for the environment variable but with a wildcard for the subdomain part. I've tried a couple of things, most recently this:

```
 SetEnvIfNoCase Referer (.*)\.sorryspammer\.com sorryspammer
```

but I am still getting visits from referrers from subdomains on sorryspammer.com. I know I'm missing something real simple. Not sure if it matters, but keep in mind that this is not going in an .htaccess file but is going in the httpd.conf file to apply the rules server wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the example you provide should and *does* work (tested on 2.2). so I guess the problem will be somewhere else.

your *env* may be getting an another value somewhere else?

(note the regexp will **not match** plain 'sorryspammer.com' - you need something like `^(.*\.)?sorryspammer\.com$`

note2: you could use `.*sorryspammer`, but that is bad practice, since it matches also things you didn't specify first - othersorryspammer.com, sorryspammer.comexample.org )

Comment: Thanks.  I did try with your Regex too and for some reason, anything.sorryspammer.com is still getting through.  Seems like both Regex examples should work.  I do have several other env rules, but any env rule will trigger the blocking of the referrer so even if it did somehow pick up another env value, it seems like the referrer would be blocked anyway.  Your answer is heplful and I appreciate it.  I'm just perplexed why it is not working.

Comment: Actually it would seem that your answer is correct (that my original code should and does work).  :)  I just tried my original code and it is now blocking unwanted subdomains from sorryspammer.  I may have had an error in my syntax when I tried originally.  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.